# Запрет повтора последних 3 паролей

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Как в Ubuntu запретить пользователю повторять последние 3 пароля?

Comment: [ключевые слова: pam_unix remember](https://www.google.com/search?q=pam_unix+remember)

Comment: впрочем, нынче, вроде, рекомендуют не pam_unix использовать, а pam_pwhistory.